# Using Gradle Build Config Fields Not Working

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, retrofit

I'm trying to use the API_URL from my build.gradle to use it with retrofit but I get the "unresolved reference" error in my RetrofitServices file so how do I fix it?

- Build.gradle:

```
    flavorDimensions "environment"
    productFlavors{

        create("develop"){
            dimension = "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".develop"
            versionNameSuffix = "-develop"
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"https://rickandmortyapi.com/\""
        }

        create("production"){
            dimension = "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".production"
            versionNameSuffix = "-production"
            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"https://rickandmortyapi.com/\""
        }
    }
```

- Retrofit services:

```
object RetrofitServices {

    val instance: Retrofit
        get()  {
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient)
                .build()
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you compiled the app, to allow the `BuildConfig` to be generated with your new field? And, do you have an `import` statement that covers your `BuildConfig` class?

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah, thank you, it was because I hadn't compiled it yet, I didn't know I had to do that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a `buildConfigField` to your Gradle setup, that tells the build tools to add the desired field to `BuildConfig`. However, adding the field does not happen right as you type into `build.gradle`. It will happen on the next build of the app. Then, the new field should appear.

So, build the app before trying to refer to the new field, and then the new field should be there for you afterwards.

If the field does not seem to show up:

- Make sure that you are importing the right `BuildConfig`
- Make sure that your `build.gradle` setup defines the `buildConfigField` for every possible build variant